# Run regression by category, bounded by +/- 10% of the category average

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have a data set with multiple categories.  I'd like to run a linear regression on each category without having to subset the data into new dfs for each category.  I've done so like this:

```
category = c(rep(c("a","b","c"),100))
x = (rep(1:5,60))
y = rnorm(300)*5
df = data.frame(category,x,y)

models = dlply(df, "category", function(dflm) 
lm(y ~ x, data = dflm))

lmcoefs = ldply(models, coef)
```

In lmcoefs, I now have the coefficients for each category stored.

**However**, I would like to run these regressions only within +/- 50% of the average of each category.  Therefore, if the average y value for category A is 10, I only want to run the regression between the y values of 5 and 15 for category A.  Same with categories B and C.

Is there a way to do this without splitting the datasets and running individual regressions?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this, but perhaps there is a shorter way.

The data

```
category = c(rep(c("a","b","c"),100))
x = (rep(1:5,60))
y = rnorm(300,10,3)  # I made these positive values 
df = data.frame(category,x,y)
```

Based on the script you already had

```
ddply(df, "category", function(d,perc=0.5){
  m=mean(d$y)
  range.min=m*(1-perc)
  range.max=m*(1+perc)
  d=d[d$y< range.max & d$y> range.min ,]
  coef(lm(y ~ x, data = d))
})

#result
category (Intercept)            x
1        a    10.04912 -0.042292670
2        b    10.37061 -0.001489721
3        c    10.04206  0.012238932
```

Instead of using dlply and then ldply, it is easier to do everything straight away with ddply.

Comment: Thanks, @Wave!  One fix - the range.min should be m*(1-perc) and the range.max should be m*(1+perc)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I didn't think through that part. But it's fixed now.